# how to use .format in np.select?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the df bellow, and I am trying to make a status column with specific dates by row

But I get the informativos about DF object instead the value of row.

Code:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'local':  ['client', 'hub'],
    'delivery_date':  [pd.to_datetime('2022-04-24'), 'null'],
    'estimated_date':  [pd.to_datetime('2022-04-24'), pd.to_datetime('2022-04-26')],
    'max_date': ['delivery_date', 'estimated_date']
    }

 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 cond = [(df["max_date"] == "delivery_date")  & (df["local"] == "client"),
         (df["max_date"] == "estimated_date") & (df["local"] == "hub")]

 choices = ["It was delivered to the customer on the date {}".format(df["delivery_date"]),
            "delivery forecast for {}".format(df["estimated_date"])]

 df["status"] = np.select(cond, choices, default = np.nan)
```

expected result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use string concatenation:

```
choices = ["It was delivered to the customer on the date " + df["delivery_date"].astype(str),
            "delivery forecast for " + df["estimated_date"].astype(str)]
df["status"] = np.select(cond, choices, default = np.nan)
```

[As @Parfait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71991039/how-to-use-format-in-np-select/71992215?noredirect=1#comment127210750_71992215) notes, if you have pandas>=1.0.0, please use astype("string") for the StringDtype introduced. So

```
choices = ["It was delivered to the customer on the date " + df["delivery_date"].astype('string'),
            "delivery forecast for " + df["estimated_date"].astype('string')]
```

Output:

```
    local        delivery_date estimated_date        max_date                                             status  
0  client  2022-04-24 00:00:00     2022-04-24   delivery_date  It was delivered to the customer on the date 2...   
1     hub                 null     2022-04-26  estimated_date                   delivery forecast for 2022-04-26
```

Comment: Consider `astype("string")` for the [StringDtype introduced and recommended since Pandas 1.0.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0/user_guide/text.html#text-data-types)` as `str` will return an `object` (mixed type) with unexpected results.

Comment: @Parfait that's an excellent suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since Series objects contain *many* values and `str.format` expects a singular value, consider Series string concatenation with [**`Series.str.cat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html).

```py
...

# ADD HELPER COLUMNS
df["delivery_note"] = "It was delivered to the customer on the date "
df["forecast_note"] = "delivery forecast for " 

choices = [
    df["delivery_note"].str.cat(df["delivery_date"]),
    df["forecast_note"].str.cat(df["estimated_date"])
]

df["status"] = np.select(cond, choices, default = np.nan)

# REMOVE HELPER COLUMNS
df.drop(["delivery_note", "forecast_note"], axis="columns", inplace=True)
```